# Button class removal doesn't render immediately

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bulma

I have a Vue app that renders a button on the screen. I'm using Bulma for css.  When the page loads the button is solid red w/white letters as it should be because there is no "is-outlined" class. When I click the button it should add the "is-outlined" class which then renders the button as red text and border on a white background.  This is what is happening when I click teh button:

1. The data on the screen goes away because I don't want to show them (this means the click event is doing what it needs to do. And, teh rest of the page is working.)
2. In the inspector in chrome I see the is-outlined class added to the button css immediately, as expected.
3. The button does not change to an outlined style.

BUT, as soon as I click something else to take focus off the button, the css is "rendered" and I get an outlined button.  It doesn't matter what I do (click on the screen, click a different window or my desktop) as soon as I do something else, the button changes color according to the class that was just added.

If I click the button again, the class is removed and the button immediately updates back to the white text on red backgrornd. (No need to click away from the button.)

So, what is the difference in rendering when I am adding a class (no immediate results) and when I am removing a class (an immediate response)?

UPDATED with full component (Still new to Vue so it may not be optimal)

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-three-quarters">
            <div>
                <button @click.stop="toggleUnLinked" id="show-unlinked" class="button is-small is-danger" :class="{'is-outlined': !this.showUnLinked}">
                    <span v-if="this.showUnLinked">Hide Unlinked </span>
                    <span v-else>Show Unlinked </span> ({{ this.unlinkedCount }})
                </button>
                <button @click.stop="toggleIgnored" id="show-ignored" class="button is-small is-dark"  :class="{'is-outlined': !this.showIgnored}">
                    <span v-if="this.showIgnored">Hide Ignored </span>
                    <span v-else>Show Ignored </span> ({{ this.ignoredCount }})
                </button>
                <button @click.stop="toggleLinked" id="show-linked"  class="button is-small is-success"   :class="{'is-outlined': !this.showLinked}">
                    <span v-if="this.showLinked">Hide Linked </span>
                    <span v-else>Show Linked </span> ({{ this.linkedCount }})
                </button>
            </div>

            <contact-modal v-if="showModal"
                           :team="current"
                           @close="showModal=false"
                           @saveLink="saveLink"
                           @keyup.esc="onEsc()"
            ></contact-modal>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>PCO ID</th>
                    <th>Contact ID</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <person-component
                        v-for="(person, index)  in people"
                        v-if="unlinkedFilter(person.status) || linkedFilter(person.status) || ignoreFilter(person.status)"
                        v-bind="person"
                        :index="index"
                        :key="person.id"
                        @linkMenu="linkMenu"
                        @unlink="unlink"
                        @ignore="ignore"
                        @restore="restore"
                ></person-component>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

function Person({id, account_id, domain_id, first_name, last_name, nickname, gender, email, phone, pco_id,
                    legacy_pco_id, contact_id, household_id, status}) {

    this.id = parseInt(id);
    this.domain_id = parseInt(domain_id);
    this.account_id = parseInt(account_id);
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.nickname = nickname;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.pco_id = pco_id;
    this.legacy_pco_id = legacy_pco_id;
    this.contact_id = parseInt(contact_id);
    this.household_id = parseInt(household_id);
    this.status = status;
}

import PersonComponent from './Person.vue';
import ContactModal from './ContactModal.vue';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            people: [],
            working: false,
            serverError: false,
            showModal: false,
            showIgnored: false,
            showLinked: false,
            showUnLinked: true,
            current: null,
            ignoredCount: 0,
            unlinkedCount: 0,
            linkedCount: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        read() {
            this.mute = true;
            this.people = [];
            window.axios.get('/api/people').then(({data}) => {
                data.forEach(person => {
                    this.people.push(new Person(person));
                });
                this.mute = false;
                this.updateCounts();
            });
        },
        linkMenu(id) {
            this.current = this.people.find(function (element) {
                return element.id == id;
            });
            this.showModal = true;
        },
        saveLink(linkDef) {
            this.showModal = false;
            window.axios.post('/api/people', linkDef)
                .then(response => {
                    this.people.find(people => people.pco_id === linkDef.pco_id).contact_id = linkDef.contact_id;
                    // this.people.find(people => people.pco_id === linkDef.pco_id).group_name = linkDef.group_name;
                    this.updateCounts();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.handle(error);
                });
        },
        unlink(id) {
            this.mute = true;
            window.axios.delete('/api/people/' + id).then(({response}) => {
                this.people.find(person => person.id === id).contact_id = null;
                // this.people.find(person => person.id === id).group_name = null;
                this.mute = false;
                this.updateCounts();
            });
        },
        ignore(id) {
            this.mute = true;
            window.axios.post('/api/people/' + id + '/ignore', {_method: 'delete'}).then(({response}) => {
                let index = this.people.findIndex(person => person.id === id);
                this.people[index].status = 0;
                this.mute = false;
                this.updateCounts();
            });
        },
        restore(id) {
            this.mute = true;
            window.axios.get('/api/people/' + id + '/restore').then(({response}) => {
                let index = this.people.findIndex(person => person.id === id);
                this.people[index].status = 1;
                this.mute = false;
                this.updateCounts();
            });
        },
        updateCounts(){
            let ic = 0; let uc = 0; let lc = 0;

            this.people.forEach(function(element){
                if (element.status == 0 ) { ic++; }
                else if (element.status == 1 ) { uc++; }
                else if (element.status == 2 ) { lc++; }
            });

            this.ignoredCount = ic;
            this.unlinkedCount = uc;
            this.linkedCount = lc;
        },
        toggleIgnored() {
            this.showIgnored = !this.showIgnored;
        },
        toggleLinked() {
            this.showLinked = !this.showLinked;
        },
        toggleUnLinked() {
            this.showUnLinked = !this.showUnLinked;
        },
        ignoreFilter(status) {
            return (status == 0 && this.showIgnored) ? true : false;
        },
        unlinkedFilter(status) {
            return (status == 1 && this.showUnLinked) ? true : false;
        },
        linkedFilter(status) {
            return (status == 2 && this.showLinked) ? true : false;
        },
        close() {
            this.showModal = false;
        },
        onEsc() {
            this.showModal = false;
        },
        handle(error) {
            this.serverError = true;
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        mute(val) {
            document.getElementById('mute').className = val ? "on" : "";
        }
    },
    components: {
        PersonComponent,
        ContactModal
    },
    created() {
        this.read();
    }
}
</script>
<style>
#app {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.heading h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to include the entire component for reference?

Comment: why do you have a `v-model` on a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and a solution.  The button was not changing to an outlined style until I moved away from it because the button was still "focused" and the focused style was being rendered.  This was happening in Chrome and here is a better explanation as to what is happening:

> "It's rather focused than active, the button has :focus pseudo class
>   styling. It seems Chrome makes buttons focused when they clicked,
>   while others don't."

https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/482

I "fixed" my problem by converting the buttons to anchors and using the button style.  Links are not treated the same way as buttons by chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use @click.stop to stop propagation, otherwise you are catchong all the click events